# How to allow rotation of youtube fullscreen or AVFullscreenVideoController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, autorotate

AVFullscreenVideoController is the view controller when playing youtube fullscreen in ios8. And I can allow it to rotate by manipulating app delegate method

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     /*
     if view controller is AVFullscreenVideoController or MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController or MPMoviePlayerViewController"
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
     */
}
```

My objective is to keep the current UIInterfaceOrientationMask of my view controllers and allow rotation to the fullscreen video when playing.

How can I do the same effect without adding code in the appdelegate.m? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i found out that fullscreenvideocontroller depends on what you allowed your device to do. Either in target > general > device orientation or in app delegate

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
```

I just made sure that if my rootviewcontroller is a navigation controller as a rootviewcontroller, i have to implement this methods to put back control to my other view controllers

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

And in the case that the view controller presenting the fullscreenvideocontroller is strictly in portrait, refer to this post

[Allow video on landscape with only-portrait app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598848/allow-video-on-landscape-with-only-portrait-app/26618777#26618777)